# Cant send file using socket(python)

Tags: python, django, serversocket

I wwant to send file to my computer using django site. I want to send file from one machine to other machine through my site.

I have [Errno 111] Connection refused

code of client:

```
class Server:

    def __init__(self):
        self.connect_client()
        self.input_blend_file = open('data/proba.blend', 'wb')
        self.buffer = memoryview(bytearray(1024 * 1024 * 10))
        self.num_bytes = 1
        self.receive_file()
        self.close_connection(self.server_socket)

    def receive_file(self):
        while self.num_bytes:
            self.toread = 1024 * 1024 * 10
            self.view = self.buffer[:]
            while self.toread:
                self.num_bytes = self.conn.recv_into(self.view, self.toread)
                self.view = self.view[self.num_bytes:]
                self.toread -= self.num_bytes
                if self.num_bytes == 0:
                    self.buffer = self.buffer[:-self.toread]
                    break

            self.input_blend_file.write(self.buffer)
        self.input_blend_file.close()

    def connect_client(self):
        self.server_socket = socket.socket()
        self.server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.server_socket.bind(('', 80))
        self.server_socket.listen(1)
        self.conn, self.address = self.server_socket.accept()

    def close_connection(self, choosed_socket):
        choosed_socket.close()
```

Code of site:

```
class FileReceiver:

def __init__(self, file, ip_client):
    self.infile_name = file
    self.ip_client = ip_client
    self.send_file_server()

def connect_server(self):
    self.client_socket = socket.socket()
    self.client_socket.connect((self.ip_client, 80))

def send_file_server(self):
    self.connect_server()
    self.sf = self.client_socket.fileno()
    self.lf = open(self.infile_name, 'rb')
    self.client_socket.sendfile(self.lf)

    self.close_connection(self.client_socket)

def close_connection(self, choosed_socket):
    choosed_socket.close()
```

My problem is on this line:

```
    self.client_socket.connect((self.ip_client, 80))
```

I opend port on machine but it doesnt work.